# Access 2010 can view or edit previous records

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I think this should be a relatively easy fix as I could do this in Access 2003, and 2007.

I setup my database to have 1 form for editing records, and another form for viewing them. No VB involved.  The problem I'm having in Access 2010 is that if I set the attribute for the form "Data Entry = Yes" I can't pull up previously entered records to be able to edit them.  I can enter new records with no problem.  If I set data entry = no then I can pull up previous records.

What would I need to do to be able to edit previous records and create new ones using the same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your form have the options:
Form - Format - Navigation Buttons = Yes
Form - Data - Allow Additions = Yes

The form will have the the button for a new record at the bottom. (triangle with a star)

Comment: I have all those set already still no go.  It doesn't work even when the form is attached to just a single table.